# ValueError: Wrong expected array shape - Keras Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I have used a CNN to classify multiclass images, I'm using Keras with Tensorflow Backend

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(nb_filters2, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes_num, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and the fit steps:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=samples_per_epoch,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    callbacks=cbks,
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

but when run it, I encounter this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_6 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (9,)
```

How should I fix my code? My images has 3 channels

Comment: Do you receive this error when running this specific code? I suspect this error is observed when running `model.train` and feeding it an incorrectly shaped target array. Please include your code around `model.train`

Comment: I have added the fit steps and the data generator

Comment: According to https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/ `input_shape` is `(batch, height, width, channels)`. Whereas you have width before height.

Comment: Also with `class_mode='categorical'` your `y` will have `shape=(classes_num,classes_num)`. Your output layer only has `shape=(classes_num,)`

Comment: thank you for pointing out that. However I set the parameter of them to all equal to each other, so that should not be the main problem, I think?

Comment: I will check with the shape of classes, thank you again

Comment: Also make sure the number of subdirectories in your data path is equal to the `classes_num`

Comment: Can you provide where `img_width` and `img_height` get assigned?

Comment: I made the img_width and img_height as 150x150

Comment: Please run `model.summary()` and post the results here. Thanks.

Comment: I have found the problem, the directory of `./validation_data` was not properly handled, thank you for your help